# Is below description of the difference between laws and principles of physics correct?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, laws-of-physics

Could some one provide elaborated answer whether description of the difference between laws and principles of physics, which I found on the Internet
(https://sciencing.com/difference-between-law-and-principle-in-physics-12760897.html)
correct? If indeed there's a  difference, then
should physics's principles (such as Heisenberg's uncertainty principle) be mathematically derivable from the mathematical apparatus of more general physics's laws?

"A law is an important insight about the nature of the universe. A law can be experimentally verified by taking into account observations about the universe and asking what general rule governs them. Laws may be one set of criteria for describing phenomena such as Newton's first law (an object will remain at rest or move at a constant velocity motion unless acted upon by an external force) or one equation such as Newton's second law (F = ma for net force, mass, and acceleration).

Laws are deduced through lots of observations and accounting for various possibilities of competing hypotheses. They don't explain a mechanism by which a phenomena occurs, but, rather, describe these numerous observations. Whichever law can best account for these empirical observations by explaining phenomena in a general, universalized manner is the law that scientists accept. Laws are applied to all objects regardless of scenario but they are only meaningful within certain contexts.

A principle is a rule or mechanism by which specific scientific phenomena work. Principles typically have more requirements or criteria when it can be used. They generally require more explanation to articulate as opposed to a single universal equation.

Principles can also describe specific values and concepts such as entropy or Archimedes principle, which relates buoyancy to the weight of displaced water. Scientists typically follow a method of identifying a problem, collecting information, forming and testing hypotheses and drawing conclusions when determining principles."

Here is another quote I found on the Internet
(https://www.quora.com/In-physics-what-is-the-difference-between-a-theory-a-law-and-a-principle), which is related to the subject matter of my question:

"That said, “theory,” “law,” and “principle” do have somewhat different usages from each other, and they may have at least one meaning in physics that is slightly different than the usual meaning.

Principle means “axiom,” more or less. It usually refers to a basic relation between more than one fundamental concept in a theory. For example, the principle of momentum conservation and the principle of inertia are fundamental parts of classical Newtonian physics.

Theory as in “String theory,” “quantum field theory,” or “Newton’s theory of gravity,” often means a collection of definitions and relations that work together to possibly explain a large body of experiments and observations. The principles of a theory should make it clear how to explain or predict any phenomenon in its domain. Developing ideas to the point where they form a theory in this sense is a lot of work and usually involves many very smart people. A theory in this sense need not be experimentally verified, but it is expected to be thorough, consistent, and well-developed.

However, physicists will also use “theory” mean to “idea” in the way that most other people do. For example, “oh, that’s just a theory” or “that’s an interesting theory.” Context is important.

Law is a label used by physicists in the past that seems to have fallen out of fashion lately. It may mean roughly the same thing as “principle,” as in “Newton’s Law of Gravitation.” You may also see it used to refer to an empirical observation that may or may not have a theoretical explanation. “Boyle’s Law” is an example of this use."

Please read below supplied link which is relevant to subject matter of this question:
https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/deep-in-thought-what-is-a-law-of-physics-anyway/

Also note this:
"Constructor Theory is a new approach to formulating fundamental laws in physics. Instead of describing the world in terms of trajectories, initial conditions and dynamical laws, in constructor theory laws are about which physical transformations are possible and which are impossible, and why. This powerful switch has the potential to bring all sorts of interesting fields, currently regarded as inherently approximative, into fundamental physics. These include the theories of information, knowledge, thermodynamics, and life."
https://www.constructortheory.org/

Comment: 1. Please cite your sources properly - "the internet" is not a proper citation. Link to your sources and use `>blockquote formatting` to delinate quotes. 2. "Is this correct?" questions are a poor fit for our Q&A model, since "Yes" or "No" is too short to even submit as an answer. 3. "Law" or "principle" are more colloquial terms rather than technical terms with a fixed meaning, see e.g. [related discussion on philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/76918). What is the question about physics as a natural science here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128465/discussion-on-question-by-alex-is-below-description-of-the-difference-between-la).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no authoritative definition that will allow you to distinguish definitively between the meanings of the words law, theory and principle. You may find people who prefer to them in particular ways, and there are certain contexts in which their use has become conventional (such as Boyle's law and the HUP).

Were you to create a Venn diagram to illustrate the potential interpretations of each word, you would find considerable overlap. The words law, rule and principle tend to be used only in connection with ideas that have been proven to some extent by experiment, while the word theory can be used to describe speculation.

Rule, law and principle tend to be applied to single relationships, such as the relationship between force, mass and acceleration, whereas theory often means in addition a body of ideas, such as quantum theory.

The OED defines principle by reference to theory and law as follows 'a general scientific theorem or law that has numerous special applications across a wide field'.

The OED defines law as 'a statement of fact, deduced from observation, to the effect that a particular natural or scientific phenomenon always occurs if certain conditions are present'

Merriam Webster defines theory as ' a plausible or scientifically acceptable general principle or body of principles offered to explain phenomena.' OED defines it as 'a supposition or a system of ideas intended to explain something, especially one based on general principles independent of the thing to be explained'. Collin defines it as 'a formal idea or set of ideas that is intended to explain something.' Doubtless there are many other definitions of the word offered by other dictionaries.

The point is that unlike SI units, say, there is no agreed international standard definition of words used in everyday life.

The reference quoted in your question does not provide references to any other sources of definitions, so it seems no more valid than any other interpretation of the meaning of the words.

Comment: I think when scientists, working in the field of Physics, themselves prefer to refer to certain things as "principles" and to others as "laws" - this is quite telling...

Comment: Perhaps, but I recommend that you should not read too much into it. Have you ever studied linguistics? If so, you will know that in general words do not have sharply defined meanings,, and that there is no authoritative definition of words- instead, words mean whatever, in practice, they are employed to mean. If suddenly a large number of people used the word 'car' to mean scissors, for example, then that would become one of its meanings, regardless of what any dictionaries might say!

Comment: However commonly established classification terminology in physics carries certain commonly recognized meaning and that is why there exists the difference between the meaning of the term "law" and the meaning of the term "principle". This difference is articulated in the cited by me references.

Comment: You miss my point- no reference is sufficiently authoritative where the use of language is concerned. Words mean whatever people take them to mean. It is impossible to define the scope of a word such as theory, say, with sufficient clarity that it could not be considered equivocal- and even if you could, people would still misunderstand the definition and misapply it.

Comment: However, so far there is no better way, other than words, to express the meaning... Why wouldn't you spend some time and discuss/argue the terminology meaning suggested in references supplied in my question?

Comment: I would be delighted, Alex. I have extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that 'theory' may mean something that is more speculative whereas that word tends to be used more for large overarching bodies of knowledge eg theory of relativity, quantum theory, theory of evolution etc. A single speculative explanation would more correctly be a called _hypothesis_ (or _conjecture_)